# Count the occurrences of a group of words in a text column in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables as follows :

```sql
CREATE TABLE keyword_tbl
(
    WORDS VARCHAR(100), 
    TOPIC VARCHAR(100)
); 

INSERT INTO keyword_tbl 
VALUES ('leaf', 'nature'), ('leaves', 'nature'),
       ('wind', 'nature'), ('knife', 'utensils'),
       ('knives', 'utensils'), ('calf', 'animal'),
       ('calves', 'animal')

CREATE TABLE content
(
    CONTENT_ID VARCHAR(100), 
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100)
); 

INSERT INTO content 
VALUES ('uuid1', 'leaves fall in autumn like leafs'),
       ('uuid2', 'the calf is playing in the leaf, the knife' ),
       ('uuid3', 'knives cutting the wind'),
       ('uuid4', 'he says hi'),  
       ('uuid5', 'the calves running through the wind')
```

I want to be able to count the occurrences of each word per topic. My ideal output would look as follows.

| content_id | description | nature | utensils | animal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid1 | leaves fall in autumn like leafs | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| uuid2 | the calf is playing in the leaf, the knife | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| uuid3 | knives cutting the wind | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| uuid4 | he says hi | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| uuid5 | the calves running through the wind | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Explanation :

- For uuid1, we count `leaves` and `leaf` hence nature has a value of  2,
- For uuid2, we count `calf`, `leaf`, `knife` hence nature, utensils and animal have a count of 1, etc...

Is there a way for this to be done autonomously?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_split_to_table.html):

> Tokenizes a string with the given set of delimiters and flattens the results into rows.

```
SELECT c.CONTENT_ID, c.DESCRIPTION
      ,COUNT_IF(k.TOPIC = 'nature') AS nature
      ,COUNT_IF(k.TOPIC = 'utensils') AS utensils
      ,COUNT_IF(k.TOPIC = 'animal') AS animals
FROM content c
,LATERAL STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(c.description, '(),. ') s
JOIN keyword_tbl k
  ON TRIM(s.value) = k.words
GROUP BY c.CONTENT_ID, c.DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY c.CONTENT_ID;
```

Output:

[image]

To handle "leaf", "leafs" the join condition needs to be altered:

```
 -- substring
 ON  TRIM(s.value) ILIKE  k.words|| '%'

 -- only 's'
 ON  TRIM(s.value) ILIKE ANY (k.words, k.words|| 's')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create `Split` Function like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1)
)       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       
      
    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       
      
    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       
          
        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       
  
        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```

Use To get string count from your table

```
select CONTENT_ID,DESCRIPTION,
(select COUNT(1) from keyword_tbl where WORDS in (select items from Split(DESCRIPTION,' ')) AND TOPIC = 'nature') as animal,
(select COUNT(1) from keyword_tbl where WORDS in (select items from Split(DESCRIPTION,' ')) AND TOPIC = 'utensils') as nature,
(select COUNT(1) from keyword_tbl where WORDS in (select items from Split(DESCRIPTION,' ')) AND TOPIC = 'animal') as utensils from content
```

here is string split from `' '` your string in `leafs` and `leaf` are different that is not count.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a `regex` based solution out there.

```
with cte (nature, animal, utensils) as
  
(select listagg(iff(topic='nature', words,null),'\\b|\\b'),
        listagg(iff(topic='animal', words,null),'\\b|\\b'),
        listagg(iff(topic='utensils', words,null),'\\b|\\b')
 from keyword_tbl)
  
select a.*,
        regexp_count(a.description,nature) as nature,
        regexp_count(a.description,utensils) as utensils,
        regexp_count(a.description,animal) as animal
from content a
cross join cte;
```

**Notes**:

`|` works like an OR condition

`\\b` adds [word boundaries](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#:%7E:text=a%20word%20character.-,%5Cb%3A%20word%20boundary.,-%5CB%3A%20not%20a), but feel free to modify as desired